# variable in Makefile not recognized by make correctly

Tags: makefile

Here is the related rules for the variable:

```
LIBAD = libadard.a

install: $(CRSLIB)/$(LIBAD)

$(CRSLIB)/$(LIBAD): $(LIBAD)

$(LIBAD): $(OBJECTS1) 

OBJECTS1 = $(LIBAD)(libadardV.o)\
    $(LIBAD)(a_delbb.o)     $(LIBAD)(a_getbkm.o)\
    ...

$(LIBAD)(a_getbkm.o): a_getbkm.p \
    $(KINCDIR)/dbug.h \
    $(PRIMINC)/systypes.h \
    $(PRIMINC)/externs.h \
    $(PRIMINC)/reserrs.h \
    $(KINCDIR)/ltypes.h \
    $(KINCDIR)/except.h \
    $(PRIMINC)/u_pr_bkmsg.h \
    $(CRSINC)/sqlerrs.h \
    $(PDBINC)/systypes.th \
    $(PRIMINC)/u_pr_bkmsg.th \
    $(INFORMINC)/sqlca.h
```

if i run "make install", here's what i got:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/sqlca.h', needed by `libadard.a(a_getbkm.o)'.  Stop.
```

For testing purpose, i added this rule in the makefile just to check the value of this variable $(INFORMINC):

```
PHONY: all
all: ; @echo $(INFORMINC)
```

And the output is correct:

```
mtang@rv02 release>make all
/informix-rv02_1/incl/esql
```

i also checked under the directory "/informix-rv02_1/incl/esql", the file sqlca.h is there. So what went wrong?

UPDATE:

variable $(INFORMINC) is not defined in this makefile. It is defined in a Makerules file sitting at the root level, and that Makerules is included by this Makefile:

```
include ../../Makerules
```

UPDATE 2:

Problem solved. Thanks @Roland Illig for the clue. In Makerules, INFORMINC is defined as:

```
INFORMIXDIR := $(MY_INFORMIXDIR)
INFORMIX := $(INFORMIXDIR)
INFORMINC := $(INFORMIX)/incl/esql
```

I just copied that last line where INFORMINC is defined and paste it in the makefile. And it worked. I am not sure if i totally understand the reason behind this, but that certainly gives me some experience to deal with similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BSD Make (and I think in many other implementations, too), the dependency lines are evaluated eagerly, at the time of parsing. So when you define the `INFORMINC` variable at a later point, it will not influence the dependency rule.

The shell command in the `all` target is evaluated lazily, just before executing it. Therefore you see its value.

See also https://mail-index.netbsd.org/tech-pkg/2016/05/26/msg016900.html, where I explained this topic a litle more verbosely.

Comment: The INFORMING variable is defined in a Makerules file, and that file is included by this makefile, at the very beginning. Does it make the definition come late?

Comment: When the Makerules are included at the beginning, I’m out of ideas. What about running Make in debug mode?

Comment: Somehow the definition of INFORMINC wasn't passed from Makerules to this makefile correctly, or on time. I have to copy the definition of the variable and paste it in the makefile to make it work.

Comment: You have to move the `include` line so it comes _before_ any use of the variables that are defined in the included file, as part of a target or prerequisite list.  Included files are parsed as if they were inserted into the makefile at the location where the `include` line is found.